# Create file pair channel from channel of file paths in Nextflow DSL2

Tags: pipeline, bioinformatics, nextflow

I collected and passed a list of files to a process for further processing by PROCESS1{}:

```
    Channel.empty()
        .mix( reads )
        .map {sample, files -> files}
        .collect()
        .set { coassembly_reads }
    
    PROCESS1( coassembly_reads )
```

Where reads was created from:

```
# in nextflow.config
reads = './raw-data/*_R{1,2}*.fastq.gz'
# in workflow{}
reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )
```

In short, based on the user's experimental design, some of the fastq files may be combined. For example, Sample1_R{1,2}.fastq may be combined with Sample2_R{1,2}.fastq.

After PROCESS1{} these files are emitted as a path:

```
path("reads/*gz"), emit: combined_reads_ch
```

Which may look something like this:

```
[/path/to/file/Sample1_R1.fastq, /path/to/file/Sample1_R2.fastq, /path/to/file/Sample1_Sample2_R1.fastq, /path/to/file/Sample1_Sample2_R2.fastq]
```

I am desiring a new channel which has these samples grouped:

```
[Sample1, [/path/to/file/Sample1_R1.fastq, /path/to/file/Sample1_R2.fastq], Sample1_Sample2, [/path/to/file/Sample1_Sample2_R1.fastq,/path/to/file/Sample1_Sample2_R2.fastq]]
```

Then, this channel would be passed to downstream processes in the same way 'reads' could be passed:

```
reads = Channel.fromFilePairs( params.reads )
```

I have tried things such as:

```
combined_reads = COASSEMBLY.out.combined_reads_ch.flatten().map { file ->
    def prefix = file(file).name =~ /^(.*?)_R[12]/ ? file(file).name =~ /^(.*?)_R[12]/[0][1] : file(file).name
    def matchingFiles = combined_reads.findAll { file(it).name =~ /${prefix}_R[12]/ }
    return [prefix, matchingFiles.collect { it }]
}
```

And:

```
combined_reads = COASSEMBLY.out.combined_reads_ch.flatten().map { file ->
    def prefix = file().getBaseName() =~ /^(.*?)_R[12]/ ? file().getBaseName() =~ /^(.*?)_R[12]/[0][1] : file().getBaseName()
    def matchingFiles = combined_reads.findAll { it().getBaseName() =~ /${prefix}_R[12]/ }
    return [prefix, matchingFiles.collect { it().toString() }]
}
```

However, these are not compatible with Nextflow DLS2 and I think I am missing some channel functionality which may be useful.

Thanks!

EDIT

I got this to work using the following code:

```
    def combined_reads = COASSEMBLY.out.combined_reads_ch

    combined_reads
        .flatten()
        .map{ file ->
            def sample = file.name.replaceAll("_R[12].fastq.gz", "")
            tuple(sample, file)
        }
        .groupTuple()
        .set{ grouped_reads }
```